# Bootstrap 4 - Tooltip and Popover Alignment issues with Perfect Scrollbar

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, tooltip, popover, perfect-scrollbar

I have Deactivated browser scrollbar and using perfect scrollbar instead inside a content `div`

**So what's the issue?**

The issue is triggered with alignment of tooltip and popover.

Please download the code from [github repo](https://github.com/Yusufzai/Issue---bs-4-tooltip-and-popover-on-perfectscroll.git)

**So what to do after downloading the code form github repo.**

Click the tooltip or popover button and try to scroll the content window the popver/tooltip will stick to the window instead of scroll top or scroll bottom with button element.

```
$('.bs-tooltip').tooltip();

$('.bs-popover').popover();


const ps = new PerfectScrollbar('.scroll', {
    wheelSpeed:.5,
    swipeEasing:!0,
    minScrollbarLength:40,
    maxScrollbarLength:300
});
```

Comment: can you create a minimal working example here that reproduces the issue... it'll be easier to help that way

Comment: @AkberIqbal Yes I have created it on my github repo please download it